# Erlang HIPE on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, erlang, hipe

When compiling Erlang or Elixir code on Windows 10 I get this warning: `this system is not configured for native-code compilation.` Is HIPE available for Windows 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to find an "official" answer to this question, I stumbled upon [an erlang-questions post](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2011-June/059486.html) by Mikael Pettersson, June 2011:

> > What exactly is the status of HiPE on the Windows platform?
>
> Same as before, namely that it's not supported but it's probably possible
> to support it if you accept a 4KB per-native-thread memory consumption
> penalty.  FP exn handling must also be implemented, but I did a
> prototype of that some time ago.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that HiIPE is **not** supported on Windows. I see lots of older comments to that effect and, according to recent RabitMQ documentation, "HiPE is not available at all on some platforms, notably including Windows."